# Why does the expression "a, b = 5" set a to 5, but b to nil in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
(irb) a, b = 5
a => 5
b => nil
```

Shouldn't that be the other way around? What is actually happening here?

Comment: Multiple assignment treats the right-hand side of the expression as a splatted array. `a, b = 5` is interpreted as `a, b = *[5]`

Comment: If you want to assign the value to both variables, use `a = b = 5`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I was writing this my coworker discovered why:

Ruby treats `a, b = 5` as `a, b = 5, nil`

In Python3, a `TypeError` is thrown.

Comment: If you're used to JavaScript, where `var a, b = 5` is two separate assignments, this will come as a surprise. In Ruby, list assignment is more like `(a, b) = (5, nil)` when expanded. The *left-hand side* is treated as a list. Things get even more confused with `a, b = 5, c = 3` which results in `a = 5, b = 3, c = 3`.

Comment: `a, b = 5, c = 3` is less confusing if you read it as -> `a, b = *[5, c = 3]`

Answer (score 2):

In order to assign a value to `b` using multiple assignment you'd have to give it a second value.

```
a, b = 5, 6

a = 5
b = 6
```

When you don't supply a second value, Ruby gives `b` a value of `nil`

Answer (score 1):

This is an important Ruby feature called multiple assignment.

Multiple assignment performs multiple assignment from expressions or an array. It's a fast way to assign multiple variables at once.

If you declare three variables, but only assign values to two of them, the third will receive `nil` by default.

The Multiple Assignment portion of [this documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#assign) explains the feature and several examples.